# logical error while comparing "-" with any record existing into the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

What I am trying to do is to compare "-" which is in textbox with any record in the table and my code is:

```
string cusph = txt_phone.Text;
 tbl_custumer findcustumer = _objdb.tbl_custumer.Where(obj => obj.cus_ph == cusph).FirstOrDefault();
            if (findcustumer != null)
            {
                strCusId = findcustumer.cus_id.ToString().TrimEnd();
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('custumer already registered ')</script> ");
            }
```

The problem is that when I want to compare (obj.cus_ph == cusph) when the value of cusph is "-", the if condition becomes true and that should not happen.

Comment: Would `if (findcustomer != null && cusph != "-")` work for you?

Comment: And what is the content of findcustumer ? there's a customer that his cus_ph is "-" ?

Comment: i have already done this 'if (findcustomer != null && cusph != "-")' and it worked but i want to know why the if condition becomes true when there is no record in the table containing obj.cus_ph equal to  -

Comment: @sam5808 Just put a breakpoint and check what value is in `findcustumer`. Simple, you will get your answer.